# Spring security authentication from neo4j database

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring MVC application i have added spring security

when i try to get AppUser from database before login to match with the given user credential I am getting the following error

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-12] ERROR org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.getSession': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

According to the given suggestion I have added

```
@ComponentScan(scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

to my UserDetailService but still getting the same error

my db url that was configured is following

```
db.local.url=http://neo4j:123456@localhost:7474
```

If I do authentication using hard coded user then I am able to login
After login i can do all sort of communication with the database

but before login I am getting the above error

How to fix this ???

gist of my code

```
https://gist.github.com/sazzadislam-dsi/6a6a21216e39184e54d0c074332bb372
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `@EntityScan("<your package where entities are saved>")` below `@SpringBootApplication`

It works in my case.